# Length of objects in Firebase list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have next Firebase database structure:

```
posts
    | 
    post
       |
       comments
              | comment 1
              | comment 2
```

This is a collection of posts, each post has a collection of comments. I want to output in the post the number of comments:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="post$ | async; let post">
    {{ post.comments?.length }}
</ng-container>
```

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what can you see if you insert only {{ post.comments}} and {{ post}}?

Comment: @ForestG i can get any field of post, even comments, but `.length` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the one you wrote is the way Firebase is saving your data?
They cannot save lists as array, but they usually convert them to maps having as key the index.

So, probably, your `post.comments` is not an array but a map. Try use size instead of length.
If it is not a map but an object (I'm not sure about this), you should use `Object.keys(post.comments).size` instead.

Comment: this is how it looks in database: http://prntscr.com/j6vq46 .
`{{ (post.comments)?.size }}` also does not work

Comment: then I suppose that when you retrieve your `post` object, it will be an `Object` and also `post.comments` will be. Then `Object.keys(post.comments).keys()` should give you an `Array` of the keys (to be clear, `-LaGk....`) and it being an `Array` has a property length